# How to find the distribution of a multivariate normal with mean 0?

Tags: determinant, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I am relatively new to higher-level statistics and I just cannot seem to wrap my head around this. I am trying to derive ELBO for a Variational Autoencoder. Here is the formula for the PDF of a Multivariate Normal Distribution I was given:

$$p(a) = (det(2 \pi \Sigma))^{\frac{-1}{2}}exp(-\frac{1}{2}(a-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(a-\mu))$$

I'm then told to derive $$p(z,x) = p(z)p(x|z)$$ where $$p(z) = N(z;0,I)$$ and $$p(x|z) = Bernoulli(x; f(x))$$

In this model, x is a fixed datapoint in a dataset I am trying to maximize the log-likelihood of. Z is the set of latent space variable for that datapoint.

If the mean is $0$, then the result of the left-hand determinant section is undefined, because $0^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is undefined. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are z, x, a related to each other? There seem to be some details missing from the question.

Comment: a is just a placeholder given in the equation, x is a fixed datapoint, and z is the latent space variable for that datapoint. Sorry for the confusion, I wasn't sure if it was relevant or not.

Comment: If the mean $\mu$ is a zero vector, it does not imply that the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is a zero matrix.

Comment: Yes, but would (det(2*pi*Identity))^{-1/2} still be undefined? Removing pi from the determinant would be (0^d * det(2*identity))^{-1/2} = 0^{-1/2}?

Comment: The matrix $2 \pi I$  has $2 \pi$ on the diagonal and 0 elsewhere ($I$ is identity). So the determinant of this matrix is simply $(2 \pi)^n$, assuming the matrix is $n \times n$. Now $det(2 \pi I)^{-1/2} = \{(2 \pi)^n\}^{-1/2}$, which is well defined. Does that make sense?

Comment: I just realized ive made the most idiotic mistake of my entire career. I was subbing mu into pi. thank you for being patient with me I am so embarassed

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Happy to help!